# Python declaring a numpy matrix of lists of lists

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I would like to have a numpy matrix that looks like this
[int, [[int,int]]]
I receive an error that looks like this "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence."

below is the declaration

```
def __init__(self):
    self.path=np.zeros((1, 2))
```

I attempt to assign a value to this in the line below

```
routes_traveled.path[0, 1]=[loc]
```

loc is a list and routes_traveled is the object

Comment: Take a look at the docs here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html. If you want to specify the shape (1,2) you need to pass that in as a sequence, like @unutbu says in his answer. Otherwise it will assume the '2' is the optional datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want a higher dimensional array, say 3d, or do you really want a 2d array whose elements are Python `lists`.  Real lists, not numpy arrays?

One way to put lists in to an array is to use `dtype=object`:

```
In [71]: routes=np.zeros((1,2),dtype=object)
In [72]: routes[0,1]=[1,2,3]
In [73]: routes[0,0]=[4,5]

In [74]: routes
Out[74]: array([[[4, 5], [1, 2, 3]]], dtype=object)
```

One term of this array is 2 element list, the other a 3 element list.

I could have created the same thing directly:

```
In [76]: np.array([[[4,5],[1,2,3]]]) 
Out[76]: array([[[4, 5], [1, 2, 3]]], dtype=object)
```

But if I'd given it 2 lists of the same length, I'd get a 3d array:

```
In [77]: routes1=np.array([[[4,5,6],[1,2,3]]])
Out[77]: 
array([[[4, 5, 6],
        [1, 2, 3]]])
```

I could index the last, `routes1[0,1]`, and get an array: `array([1, 2, 3])`, where as `routes[0,1]` gives `[1, 2, 3]`.

In this case you need to be clear where you talking about arrays, subarrays, and Python lists.

---

With `dtype=object`, the elements can be anything - lists, dictionaries, numbers, strings

```
In [84]: routes[0,0]=3
In [85]: routes
Out[85]: array([[3, [1, 2, 3]]], dtype=object)
```

Just be ware that such an array looses a lot of the functionality that a purely numeric array has.  What the array actually contains is pointers to Python objects - just a slight generalization of Python lists.

Comment: your first suggestion I think will work. Doea it matter that my first column is just an int and my second is an object?

Answer (score 1):

Did you want to create an array of zeros with shape `(1, 2)`? In that case use `np.zeros((1, 2))`.

```
In [118]: np.zeros((1, 2))
Out[118]: array([[ 0.,  0.]])
```

In contrast, `np.zeros(1, 2)` raises `TypeError`:

```
In [117]: np.zeros(1, 2)
TypeError: data type not understood
```

because [the second argument to `np.zeros`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) is supposed to be the `dtype`, and 2 is not a value `dtype`.

---

Or, to create a 1-dimensional array with a custom dtype consisting of an int and a pair of ints, you could use

```
In [120]: np.zeros((2,), dtype=[('x', 'i4'), ('y', '2i4')])
Out[120]: 
array([(0, [0, 0]), (0, [0, 0])], 
      dtype=[('x', '<i4'), ('y', '<i4', (2,))])
```

I wouldn't recommend this though. If the values are all ints, I think you would be better off with a simple ndarray with homogeneous integer dtype, perhaps of shape (nrows, 3):

```
In [121]: np.zeros((2, 3), dtype='<i4')
Out[121]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

Generally I find using an array with a simple dtype makes many operations from building the array to slicing and reshaping easier.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I am not looking for an matrix of ints. I need a matrix that looks like [int, [[int,int]]]. A matrix with first column being an int and the second being a list of lists of ints

Comment: Refresh your page. I addressed that in the second part of my answer.

Comment: This is closer to what I'm looking for. However I would like for the second column to support a list of of the points. While it currently only supports 1 point.

Comment: Unless I did not seperate each of the points into their own list

Comment: I think the answer you gave for this question might work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106287/pythonic-way-to-create-a-numpy-array-from-a-list-of-numpy-arrays